# Is it possible to construct a quiver diagram for electromagnetism?

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, gauge-theory

I have been trying to learn about quiver diagrams and quiver gauge theory for a summer project.  All of the lecture notes/papers on the topic give example diagrams that are mathematically simple but don't correspond to any real theory.

I was wondering, what does the quiver diagram for fields I already know about (electromagnetism, scalar spin 0 fields, dirac spinors etc) look like?

Comment: You'll have to be more precise what you mean by a "quiver diagram" in this case. For instance, I've only seen quiver diagrams appear in theories with at least two different gauge groups and a matter field that transforms in the bifundamental representation. What do you even *mean* by "quiver diagram" for a theory that's not of this type?

Comment: That is the kind of quiver diagram I mean.  I don't really understand the physics of them so I wanted to see a diagram of a field/field I all ready know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such quiver diagram for electromagnetism because it is not a quiver gauge theory. A quiver gauge theory for which you can draw  a quiver diagram is a gauge theory with at least 2 gauge groups $\mathrm{U}(N_i)$ and at least one matter field field that transforms in the fundamental representations of two of these groups. In addition the theory is usually assumed to be supersymmetric.

Neither the standard model nor its minimal supersymmetric extension (MSSM) is a quiver gauge theory, either, because they have fields you can't fit into the quiver because they transform in the wrong representations. However, there *is* a "minimal quiver extension" of the MSSM constructed in [*"Building the Standard Model on a D3-brane"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0508089v2) by H. Verlinde and M. Wijnholt.